# How to deal with overflow in grid elements inside a flexbox container?

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, overflow, css-grid

I hope you can help me (Im new at CSS)

I want to create a social media feed like instagram but with all the elements evenly spaced out from each other but the elements themselves use a grid display.

Heres what I have at the moment (Also a codepen for easier test)
https://codepen.io/Lisks/pen/QWjYpOp

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <header class="header">Header</header>
        <div class="userSettings">Settings</div>
        <nav class="categoryNav">
            <span>Filter</span>
            <ul class="categories">
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 1</li>
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 2</li>
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 3</li>
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 4</li>
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 5</li>
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 6</li>
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 7</li>
                <li class="singleCategory">cat 8</li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
        <div class="topPosts">topPosts</div>
        <div class="posts">

             <div class="piece-posts">
                <div class="piece-posts-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/03/13/09/puppy-5124947_960_720.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, maxime vero nesciunt at reiciendis nisi excepturi tempora nam corporis saepe facere sed beatae itaque tenetur hic est nulla debitis doloribus!
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-meta">
                    el meta 
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div class="piece-posts">
                <div class="piece-posts-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/03/13/09/puppy-5124947_960_720.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, maxime vero nesciunt at reiciendis nisi excepturi tempora nam corporis saepe facere sed beatae itaque tenetur hic est nulla debitis doloribus!
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-meta">
                    el meta 
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div class="piece-posts">
                <div class="piece-posts-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/03/13/09/puppy-5124947_960_720.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, maxime vero nesciunt at reiciendis nisi excepturi tempora nam corporis saepe facere sed beatae itaque tenetur hic est nulla debitis doloribus!
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-meta">
                    el meta 
                </div>          
            </div>
              <div class="piece-posts">
                <div class="piece-posts-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/03/13/09/puppy-5124947_960_720.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, maxime vero nesciunt at reiciendis nisi excepturi tempora nam corporis saepe facere sed beatae itaque tenetur hic est nulla debitis doloribus!
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-meta">
                    el meta 
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div class="piece-posts">
                <div class="piece-posts-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/03/13/09/puppy-5124947_960_720.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis tempore dignissimos tenetur dolore, sed ea quas, omnis aspernatur eius, facere in accusamus voluptate maiores temporibus veritatis neque asperiores praesentium non!
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-meta">
                    small data 
                </div>          
            </div>

            <div class="piece-posts">
                <div class="piece-posts-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/03/13/09/puppy-5124947_960_720.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum obcaecati eveniet voluptatum, esse accusamus et, quos reiciendis harum molestiae sequi a commodi nostrum iure aut cupiditate cum voluptas. Molestiae, fuga?
                </div>
                <div class="piece-posts-meta">
                    small data 
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box
}


body{
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15fr 4fr 4fr 15fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr 2fr 22fr;

  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header header"
    ". . . config"
    "category category category category"
    "topPosts posts posts posts";
}

.header{
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.userSettings{
  grid-area: config;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0.5rem
}

.categoryNav{
  grid-area: category;
  background-color: darkblue;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  color:white
}
.categories{
  display:flex; 
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.singleCategory{
  padding: .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.singleCategory:hover{
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topPosts{
  grid-area: topPosts;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
}

.posts{
  grid-area: posts;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}


 .piece-posts{
  display: grid;
  width: 75%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr ;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "image content"
    "image metadata";

}

.piece-posts-image{
  grid-area: image;
}
.piece-posts-image img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.piece-posts-content{
  grid-area: content;
}

.piece-posts-meta{
  grid-area: metadata;
}
```

The posts pack together, then they overflow at the top and finally the scrollbar appears but seems messy and not what I intended

And for some visual feedback for picturing what I want to accomplish, this but with margin between the posts (top-bottom and left-right)

https://blog.feedly.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/experiment01-smooth-scrolling.gif

Comment: IT's really unclear what the problem is, Your layout is as simple as a flexbox column https://jsfiddle.net/0498zLaq/